# I cant login to cloned image on Rackspace

Tags: authentication, ssh, port, rackspace

I have an instance in my account that I can login to ssh with port 27891. When I clone it ( make an image and from an image a server) I can´t access it with the password Rackspace gave me to root.

I´ve tried with port 22 and with port 27891 and neither work.

I´ll appreciate help!!

Thanks..

Comment: I'm in the progress of trying this out, but does it give you a new password upon creation? Are you using the UI or an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloned servers don't have the same password**. You'll need to grab the admin password either from the UI or the API you're using. If you need to, you can always change the password as well:

[image: Change Password dialog]

On the other hand, I highly recommend using SSH keypairs with Rackspace boxes. You'll need to use the API (or one of the SDKs), but it makes it much easier to manage the boxes. Additionally, the `authorized_keys` file will be on each of the cloned images.

Example cloning code, using [pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax) (the Python library for Rackspace):

```py
# Authenticate with Rackspace -- also works against OpenStack/Keystone
pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_credential_file(os.path.expanduser("~/.rax_creds"))
cs = pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers(region="DFW")

# Could use the API to get image IDs
# This one is for Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) (PVHVM beta)
image = u'62df001e-87ee-407c-b042-6f4e13f5d7e1'
flavor = u'performance1-1'

# Create a server (solely to make an image out of it, for this example)
base_server = cs.servers.create("makeanimageoutofme",
                                image,
                                flavor,
                                key_name="rgbkrk")

# It takes a little while to create the server, so we poll it until it completes
base_server = pyrax.utils.wait_for_build(base_server, verbose=True)

# Create image
im = base_server.create_image("base_image")
image = cs.images.get(im)
# Wait for image creation to finish
image = pyrax.utils.wait_until(image, "status", "ACTIVE", attempts=0)

# Note that a clone can be a bigger flavor (VM size) if needed as well
# Here we use the flavor of the base server
clone_server = cs.servers.create(name="iamtheclone",
                                 image=image.id,
                                 flavor=base_server.flavor['id'])

clone_server = pyrax.utils.wait_for_build(clone_server, verbose=True)
```

Within each of the created machines, the generated credentials are in `base_server.adminPass` and `clone_server.adminPass`. To access the box, use `base_server.accessIPv4` and `clone_server.accessIPv4`.

However, I *highly* recommend using SSH keypairs.

Comment: I see, well I already can access via java console, there is not a way to access via terminal (using Putty) ? Im sure not :S . I can´t use keys in this project btw.

Regards.

Comment: Well you could always change the password either from the java console or by clicking "Change Password" on mycloud.rackspace.com via Actions (upper right).

Comment: hehe yes, I´ll try, thanks ALL, for the quick responses ... this site is the best